# Delphi Double to Objective C double

Tags: objective-c, delphi, double

I am looking a few hours for some solution of this problem, but I don't get how it works. I have a hex string from delphi double value : 0X3FF0000000000000. That value should be 1.0. It is 8 byte long, first bit is sign, next 11 are exponent and the rest is mantissa. So for me is this hex value equals 0 x 10^(1023). Maybe I am wrong somewhere, but it doesn't matter. The point is, I need this hex value to convert into objective c double value. If I do:  `(double)strtoll(hexString.UTF8String, NULL,16);` I get: 4.607...x 10 ^18. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That isn't strictly a delphi double, it's a standard IEEE-754 double.  The exponent is encoded with an offset of 1023, making your value `10^(0) = 1.0`.  How did you end up with a hex string?  It doesn't seem a sensible format for the purpose...

Comment: It is 1.0 in IEEE 64-bit binary. See (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) for the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that trying to cast in this way ends up with a call to an implicit type conversion (calls `_ultod3` or `_ltod3`) that alters the underlying data.  In fact, even trying to do this seems to do the same thing :

```
UINT64 temp1 = strtoull(hexString, NULL, 16);
double val = *&temp1;
```

But if you cast the uint pointer to a `double*` it semes to suppress the compiler's desire to try to perform a conversion. Something like this should work :

```
UINT64 temp1 = strtoull(hexString, NULL, 16);
double val = *(double*)&temp1;
```

At least this works with the MS C++ compiler... I imagine the objective C compiler would cooperate as well.